# Dynamic Pivot table group by

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

Plz help
Here is dynamic pivot table, how can I do group by

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM #tmpBusdatewise) AS name


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT datewise, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #tmpBusdatewise
    PIVOT(SUM(totlcnt) 
          FOR name IN (' + @ColumnName + ') ) AS PVTTable'-- group by ' + @columnname


EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Thanks
Samir

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the source table must be in a inner query

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM #tmpBusdatewise) AS name


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N' -- Your pivoted result comes here
    SELECT datewise, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM 
    (
        -- Source table should in a inner query
        SELECT datewise,name,totlcnt
        FROM #tmpBusdatewise
    )AS P
    PIVOT
    (     
          -- Select the values from derived table P
          SUM(totlcnt) 
          FOR name IN (' + @ColumnName + ') 
    )AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks , now it is solved.

actually counting was not happening

### I added

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


declare @colmn as nvarchar(max)

SELECT @colmn= ISNULL(@colmn + ',','')  
+'sum('+ QUOTENAME(name)+') as ' + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM #tmpBusdatewise) AS name

　
SELECT
 @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
+ QUOTENAME(name)
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT name FROM #tmpBusdatewise) AS name


　
SET
 @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT datewise, ' + @colmn + '
    FROM #tmpBusdatewise
    PIVOT(SUM(totlcnt) 
          FOR name IN ('
 + @ColumnName + ') ) AS PVTTable group by datewise'
--print(@DynamicPivotQuery)

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```